# Oracle Apex Table Cell Attributes for a Page Item Label

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm using Apex 5.1.  I have a form with several display-only items.  I'd like to bold or color the label to distinguish it from the text.  I see a field for Table Cell Attributes in the Label section, but I don't know how to indicate something like Bold or Color.
By the way, I have the Escape Special Characters option set to NO so that I can display the text in the display-only field without the HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly simple.

- if your current label is `Employee Name`
- set it to bold by putting this into the label property: `<b>Employee Name</b>`

Answer (score 2):

If you want ALL the labels on a page to be bold, you should use CSS, e.g. in the page **Inline CSS** attribute add this:

```
.t-Form-label { font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey.  However when I copied the text above to the Page's CSS / Inline field, and then removed the <b></b> tags from a few fields Label / Label, the label text for that field remained normal face.  The other fields which had the <b></b> tags still there remained bold.  Is there something I have to do enable Inline CSS?

Comment: Check the page source and see if the `t-Form-label` class is on the field labels. It's possible your theme uses a different class name for item labels.

Comment: I was using the template "Optional with help" (Type = Label) for all the fields on my form.  The "Before Label" code was: 
<label for="#CURRENT_ITEM_NAME#" id="#LABEL_ID#" tabindex="999"><a class="optional-w-help" href="javascript:popupFieldHelp('#CURRENT_ITEM_ID#','&SESSION.')" tabindex="999">
I copied the template and edited it.
Original: <a class="optional-w-help"
New: <a style="text-decoration-line:none;font-weight:900"
When I use the copied template for each field, the labels are perfect.

Comment: Question: Where is the class "optional-w-help" defined?  I'm curious about the contents of that class and where I can edit it.

Comment: Hello @JeffreyKemp thanks for your help. You say why this css code : .t-Form-label{font-size: 100px;} dosen't work then your code with font-weight : bold work ? Have a good day

Comment: @user3138025 I think you'll find that in the theme templates, under shared components. Note that changing the optional-w-help class might cause issues; you could instead just add your class to it.